# Run thread first than main progress

Tags: c, multithreading, pipe

I am developing pipe communication tool with VS2010 on Win10 x64.
I created `PIPE` using `CreateNamedPipe(L"blablabla",...)`, and this is `PIPE - SERVER`. Then I wait for the `PIPE - CLIENT` connection using `ConnectNamedPipe(handle)`.

Problem occurring on here, because I am sure, cannot pass on line `ConnectNamedPipe(handle)` for waiting the client connection.
For solve this, I just created a thread which wait for the client pipe connection.

After `CreateThread(....)` then I can break the block, and connect to pipe server.

Simple implementation here, not full code.

```
DWORD WINAPI _thread_pipe_server_(LPVOID lPvoid)
{
//--------------------------- Step - 01 ---------------------------------
    g_pipe_handle = CreateNamedPipe(g_pipe_name,
        PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
        PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_WAIT,
        PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES, MAX_PIPE_BUFFER_SIZE, MAX_PIPE_BUFFER_SIZE,
        g_pipe_time, 0);

    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != g_pipe_handle)
    {
        ConnectNamedPipe(g_pipe_handle, 0);

        // Sending and receiving data...
        // --- >
        // < ---
        DisconnectNamedpipe(g_pipe_handle);
    }

    return ERROR_PROCESS;
}

int main()
{
    HANDLE h_pipe_server = CreateThread(0, 0, _thread_pipe_server_, 0, 0, 0);
    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != h_pipe_server)
    {
//--------------------------- Step - 02 ---------------------------------
        HANDLE h_pipe_client = CreateFile(g_pipe_name, GENERIC_ALL, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
        if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != h_pipe_client)
        {
            // Receiving and sending data...
            // < ---
            // --- >
            CloseHandle(h_pipe_client);
        }
    }
}
```

As I said, I am using Win10 x64, and it works well.
BUT ON WIN7 the `Step - 01` is not processing faster than `Step - 02`.
So, `h_pipe_client` cannot be valid value, because `Step - 01` has not processed yet.  How can I always run `Step - 01` father than `Step - 02`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a semaphore for this. Kind of pseudocode, don't have a windows machine ready to test:

```
DWORD WINAPI _thread_pipe_server_(LPVOID lpSemaphore)
{
    // grab the semaphore from the parameter
    auto pStep1SemaphoreHandle = static_cast<HANDLE*>(lpSemaphore);
//--------------------------- Step - 01 ---------------------------------
    g_pipe_handle = CreateNamedPipe(g_pipe_name,
        PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
        PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_WAIT,
        PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES, MAX_PIPE_BUFFER_SIZE, MAX_PIPE_BUFFER_SIZE,
        g_pipe_time, 0);
    // after the pipe is created, signal the semaphore so main thread can continue
    ReleaseSemaphore(*pStep1SemaphoreHandle, 1, nullptr);
    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != g_pipe_handle)
    {
        ConnectNamedPipe(g_pipe_handle, 0);

        // Sending and receiving data...
        // --- >
        // < ---
        DisconnectNamedpipe(g_pipe_handle);
    }

    return ERROR_PROCESS;
}


int main()
{
    // semaphore can tell us when something happened in another thread
    HANDLE step1Semaphore = CreateSemaphore(NULL, 1, 0, NULL);
    HANDLE h_pipe_server = CreateThread(0, 0, _thread_pipe_server_, &step1Semaphore, 0, 0);
    // wait until semaphore was signalled
    WaitForSingleObject(step1Semaphore, INFINITE);
    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != h_pipe_server)
    {
//--------------------------- Step - 02 ---------------------------------
        HANDLE h_pipe_client = CreateFile(g_pipe_name, GENERIC_ALL, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
        if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != h_pipe_client)
        {
            // Receiving and sending data...
            // < ---
            // --- >
            CloseHandle(h_pipe_client);
        }
    }
}
```

That's the 'general' solution anyway. In this case you could just create the handle in the main thread *before* launching the other thread...

Comment: thank you very much! what do you think about mutex? It means, I don't well about `Semaphore`.

Comment: I think you _could_ achieve something like that with a mutex, but it's not really the right tool for the "wait for signal" thing you're trying to do here. Although again, the simpler way to do this in your case is just to do the setup code synchronously, since it's not like the other thread has anything better to do than wait in the meanwhile anyway...